# Connect Google Analytics and Google custom search engine?

Tags: google-analytics, google-custom-search

Hi I want to connect google custom search engine to google analtycs, but are not sure of the procedure ...

I just have to add:

```
 var _gaq = gaq || [];

      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1']);

       _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');

        ga.type = 'text/javascript';

        ga.async = true;

        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www')

                      + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

      })();
```

????

I have to change something in the panel of google analytics?

I have to add this (the above code):

```
var _gaq = gaq || [];          
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1']);           
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

or this? :

```
var gaq;
  var _gaq = gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-YY']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'yourdoamin.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1321536?hl=en

Comment: @LuckyChingi Hello, you too have connected? or you tried now on google? I would understand if have to do something in the control panel of analtycs

Comment: I think its just on the custom search settings, link your custom search to GA like webmasters and it should be good

Comment: i read that i should to active site search tracking in control panel GA... but i not find it...

Comment: https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#report/content-site-search-overview/. There is a search option on the left bar too

Comment: yes i found it and is active...(maybe because i active it by control panel of google custom search engine). Now i have only a doubt about the code inside the page you linked... see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom site search configuration go to:
Statistics and Logs->Google Analytics
and fill in the details.

Alternatively, if you redirect all queries to a page like this:

```
www.example.com/search/?q=searchquery
```

Then you can just add this directly to Google Analytics in Admin->View Settings->Site Search Settings.

Personally I do both just to be sure.